# Запуск Minecraft из Терминала

Tags: javascript, java, electron

Решил я написать лаунчер на JS .

Да, интересная затея, но все же.
И так. С чего я начал: Первым делом естественно я подготовил сборку Minecraft.
. Для движка (Основного) я решил использовать Electron.

Написать приложение я то написал. Раскидал формочки, все готово. Подскажите мне как запускать лаунчер Minecraft.

Имею : `~/.minecraft/versions/ForgeOptiFine 1.11.2`

В директории есть файлы.

`'ForgeOptiFine 1.11.2.jar'` `'ForgeOptiFine 1.11.2.json'`
`'ForgeOptiFine 1.11.2.jar.bak'` `natives(папка)`

Пробую запустить сначала из консоли

```
javaw ForgeOptiFine\ 1.11.2.jar
```

**bash: javaw: команда не найдена**

Окей. Нет так нет.

```
java -jar ForgeOptiFine\ 1.11.2.jar
```

**Error: Could not find or load main class net.minecraft.client.Main**

Вот это уже по интересней. 
Подскажите как запустить лаунчер из консоли. Со скриптом думаю уже будет гораздо гораздо проще. 
P.S Как передать jar файлу мой ник?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нашел вот эту статью: [Minecraft Error: Could not find or load main class net.minecraft.client.main.Main](http://www.stcleaner.com/blog/2016/03/23/minecraft-error-could-not-find-or-load-main-class-net-minecraft-client-main-main/). Предлагают варианты решения проблемы:

1) **Переименовать файл .jar**

Файл Jar может быть поврежден. Переименуйте его, а затем снова запустите Minecraft.

- Нажмите File Explorer , значок на панели задач.
- Нажмите Просмотр вкладку на ленточный интерфейс.
- Проверьте скрытые элементы флажок , чтобы показать все скрытые файлы
  и папки.
- Откройте следующее расположение:   `C:\Users\имя_пользователя\AppData\Roaming\.Minecraft\Libraries\Net\Minecraft\1.6.2`
- Переименовать `Minecraft-1.6.2.jar` в `Minecraft-1.6.2.jar.old`.

2) **Запуск от администратора**

Вопросы функциональности запуска игры могут возникнуть из-за недостатка привилегий администратора. Повторно запустите приложение под администратором.

- Щелкните правой кнопкой мыши на `Minecraft` значок.
- Выберите команду *"Запуск от имени администратора"* опцию.

3) **Диагностика проблем совместимости**

Приведенная ниже информация поможет повторно запустить `Minecraft` в режиме совместимости:

- Открыть `Minecraft` контекстное меню, щелкнув правой кнопкой мыши на
  исполняемый файл.
- Нажмите <kbd>Свойства</kbd>
- Нажмите на вкладку <kbd>Совместимость</kbd>.
- Установите флажок под названием *"Запустить программу в режиме
  совместимости"*
- Выберите более раннюю версию `Windows`, а затем нажмите кнопку <kbd>OK</kbd>.

4) **Переустановка `Minecraft`**

С помощью следующих команд, сначала переименуйте папку `.Minecraft`, а затем удалите и переустановите игру.

- Выйти из программы `Minecraft` полностью.
- Запустите командную строку из под администратора
- Введите следующие команды:

  ```
  CD C:\Users\имя_пользователя\AppData\Roaming\
  REN .Minecraft .Minecraft.OLD
  Exit
  ```
- Нажмите <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> выберите пункт *"Поиск"*
- Нажмите настройки и откройте результаты поиска
- Нужно найти приложения и параметры (указать в фильтр)
- Введите `Minecraft`
- Выберите `Minecraft` из результатов поиска и нажмите кнопку *"Удалить"*
- Следуйте указаниям мастера удаления, перезагрузите компьютер
- Установить `Minecraft` заново

(Переустановка `Minecraft` возможна и другим образом, не обязательно так, как описано в этом пункте)

Answer (score 0):

Просто так (через java -jar minecraft.jar) запускать Minecraft нельзя. Нужно указать кучу аргументов, но на самом деле все не так сложно.
Загружайте TLauncher и активируйте режим разработчика. (так, что бы появилась консоль). Теперь загрузите какую-нибудь версию Minecraft и в этой консоли появится строка запуска Minecraft, которую нужно немного подредактировать и выполнить в консоли. Успехов!